# Is there a single word or expression for "off and on"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

> *"To fix your router, turn it off and on."*

One could use the phrase *power cycle* but it still seems inelegant. Is there anything more succinct?

Comment: Detail the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. More succinct, so *shortest* answer? Detail the research you've already done. Explain why words or phrases you've already considered did not work: how is *power cycle* too inelegant? Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Comment: Word requests have [special posting requirements](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reboot**

From dictionary.com:

**Reboot**-to restart (a computer) by loading the operating system; boot again.

To fix your router, **reboot** it.

Comment: Yeah. I felt a bit silly after posting because I didn't think of *restart*.

Comment: _recycle_ is another term sometimes used.